# Is there a reasonable way to pass linker flags though configure and libtool?

Tags: autotools, libtool

Context: I am trying to cross build a library (curl) which uses autotools and `libtool` using clang, which requires the `-target` flag for pretty much everything. I set the environment vars, including `CC`, `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` etc., run `./confgigure`. So far so good.

Then I do `make` and the linking fails, because `libtool` removes (among others) the `-target` option. `libtool` even has a [FAQ entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Stripped-link-flags) about this, which states that to remedy this, I should use flags such as `-Xcompiler`. Sure enough, when I run the `libtool` command with the necessary options prefixed by `-XCClinker`, it works. Except when I put that into `LDFLAGS`, the `configure` script fails instead, since it compiles its tests without `libtool`, and clang then fails due to malformed command line.

I ended up just patching `libtool` to leave unknown flags alone, but is there a sane way to pass these flags so that they work in both `configure` and vanilla `libtool`?

The only similar-ish question I found on SO is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969962/libtool-clang-let-me-pass-arguments-to-compiler-but-not-linker), but that's about stripping *more* flags for linking, not fewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I set the environment vars, including CC, CFLAGS, LDFLAGS etc., run ./confgigure. So far so good.

Not necessarily.  One *can* pass those and a few other environment variables in `configure`'s environment.  If you do, it will remember that you did, and it will use them and provide for `make` to use them too.  But you should do that only when and to the extent necessary.  SOP is to just `./configure; make`, possibly followed by `sudo make install`.

> I ended up just patching `libtool` to leave unknown flags alone, but is there a sane way to pass these flags so that they work in both `configure` and vanilla `libtool`?

When you do need `LDFLAGS` *etc*, they don't necessarily have to be specified to `configure`.  They can also be specified directly to `make`, and if you need to avoid `configure` using them during its tests then that's exactly what you should do.  For example,

```bash
./configure
make LDFLAGS="-XCClinker -target ..."
```

That's a little inconvenient because you need to specify the flags every time you run `make`, but if you're just trying to build the software, not develop it, then it's not too big a deal.

If you were trying to develop the software then you might make the build system test for Mac or directly for the need for the extra flags, and provide them itself.  That would yield the smoothest experience.  But I would hardly expect anyone who just wanted to perform one-off builds to set that up in someone else's package.

Comment: I did try to specify LDFLAGS for `make`, but only by prefix, which sets the environment. Now that you pointed it out, I quickly found the part of `make` manual which says that specifying them as args to `make` actually inhibits assignment to those variables in the Makefile. Many thanks!